How to debug Flutter web integration test in VS Code
I have followed the instructions on https://docs.flutter.dev/testing/integration-tests#test-in-a-web-browser to set up my integration tests and they run by starting starting chromedriver in one console, and then flutter drive ... in the terminal.
How do I combine all that into a launch configuration?
I tried moving the starting of chromedriver into a PrelaunchTask, but VS Code waits until it finished (which of course it never does) before it launches.
Current solution was to move everything into tasks. One main task depends on two others that run in parallel.
{
    "label": "Flutter Integration Test",
    "dependsOn": ["start chromedriver", "run flutter test"]
},
{
    "label": "start chromedriver",
    "command": "chromedriver",
    "args": [
        "--port=4444",
    ],
    "type": "shell",
    "isBackground": true,
    "problemMatcher": {
        "pattern": {
          // This is not needed but, required by the problemMatcher Object
          "regexp": "^$"
        },
        "background": {
          "activeOnStart": false,
          "beginsPattern": "ChromeDriver was started successfully on port 4444.",
          // Still figuring this out
          "endsPattern": ".*"
        }
    },
    "options": {
    }
},
{
    "label": "run flutter test",
    "command": "flutter",
    "args": [
        "drive",
        "--driver=test_driver/integration_test.dart",
        "--target=integration_test/my_test.dart",
        "--device-id=chrome"
    ],
    "type": "shell",
    "problemMatcher": {
        "pattern": {
          // This is not needed but, required by the problemMatcher Object
          "regexp": "^$"
        },
    },
    "options": {
        "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}/mypath/my_test"
    }
},

That works, in the sense that it successfully starts chromedriver and runs the integration test.
How can I reconfigure this to actually debug and step through the test?
Note that I also tried to use standard dart launch config, specifying the integration test as program, but that results in the below error.
{
    "name": "my integration test",
    "cwd": "my_project",
    "request": "launch",
    "type": "dart",
    "program": "integration_test/my_test.dart",
},


Web devices are not supported for integration tests yet.
Exited (1).

